# Usage of [xml] and [android] tags

Tags: discussion, support, tags

There are 175,000 questions tagged "xml" of which about 25,000 are also tagged "android". The questions that carry both tags are almost all about the specific XML vocabulary used to define android user interfaces.

Generally we discourage use of the "XML" tag for questions about specific XML vocabularies (it's like tagging a question "Java" when you're asking about a specific application that happens to be written in Java, when the question itself is nothing to do with Java). But the "android xml" combination is so ubiquitous that it's hard to stop the flow, and for anyone watching "xml" who knows nothing about android, it's a significant distraction.

Is there any possibility of moving all these 25,000 questions into a new [android-xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-xml) tag and then trying to get that adopted for new questions?

Comment: I just watch XML tags and ignore Android.

Comment: Just add [android] to the Ignored Tags section of your profile and you'll never have to look at these kind of questions again.

Comment: but we tag language frameworks with their language...

Comment: The vast, vast (99%) majority of the questions you're complaining about belong in android-layout.  THe small percentage left actually are about xml and android.  Creating a new tag is of approximately 0 value.  Now if you want to migrate the appropriate ones to android-layout and android, feel free (just don't drop the android tag, as nobody monitors the subtags).

Answer (score 2):

This is mostly related to Android UI layouts, which can be defined in XML. But there is already a tag for that - [android-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-layout).

Other cases include parsing XML on Android, which is a fair use of [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) + [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml).

I see no reason to use [android-xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-xml) tag.

Comment: There are many things you can do with xml on android that are not related to UI/layout

Comment: @TimCastelijns what else rather than parsing and layouts (see my updated answer)?

Comment: that's not relevant here. The point is that there are uses for xml on android other than defining layouts

Comment: @TimCastelijns One can use [tag:android] + [tag:xml] for this.

Comment: Yes, sure. But discussing this is a waste of time. Most users in the android tag are not going to use the tags the way we would like them to be used.